# How to update a array list sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How to update array order?

I have a list with property 'order' and I would like to add an object in an array.

```
{id: 1, name: 'abba', order: 0},
{id: 5, name: 'Bingo', order: 1}
{id: 2, name: 'James', order: 2},
{id: 3, name: 'Turbo', order: 3},
{id: 4, name: 'Nano', order: 4}
```

I would like to insert an object in Array and update the order.
The object needs to go in between id: 2 and id:3 and then update the order.

Comment: I would be better if you add an example of the expected output and what you have tried. I don't see the question too clear right now. If I understood, you can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert the new object at a given position, and then use a loop to update the `order` property with the index of each object.

Comment: This could be answered in so many different ways. It would be better if you teall what are your inputs, ouputs and conditions, cause I guess the position, orders, length can change.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index, splice the object and update from the given index all items with the index.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: 'abba', order: 0 }, { id: 5, name: 'Bingo', order: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'James', order: 2 }, { id: 3, name: 'Turbo', order: 3 }, { id: 4, name: 'Nano', order: 4 }],
    object = { id: 7, name: 'Giga', order: -1 },
    insertBeforeId = 3,
    index = array.findIndex(({ id }) => id === insertBeforeId);

array.splice(index, 0, object);

do {
    array[index].order = index;
} while (++index < array.length);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```